# Maximum calls a function device in cuda

Tags: cuda

I am trying call 1000000 or more time a device function on global function. But, i always have the following error: **Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location 0x0031fc24**
But the code is simple. It's possible the execution thread back from thread device to thread host asynchronously lock some resources? As we see there is not overflow in variables, so what happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "cuda.h"
#include "curand_kernel.h"

#define NDIM 30 
#define NPAR 3 

#define DIMPAR NDIM*NPAR //

__device__ float f(float *inputs){
    float t = 0.0;
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < 15; i++)
        t+= inputs[i]*0.0001;
    return t;
}

__global__ void kernel(float *pos, float *pbest){

    int thread = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    int i = 0;
    float tpbest = 0.0;

    if(thread < DIMPAR){
        do{
            tpbest = f(pbest);
            i++;
        }while(i <  1000000); //max length int 2147483648 > 1000000

    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    float *d_pos,    *h_pos;
    float *d_pbest,  *h_pbest;


    h_pos   = ( float *) malloc(sizeof( float ) * DIMPAR);
    h_pbest = ( float *) malloc(sizeof( float ) * DIMPAR);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_pos, DIMPAR   * sizeof( float ));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_pbest, DIMPAR * sizeof( float ));

    int i, numthreadsperblock, numblocks;

    numthreadsperblock = 512;
    numblocks = (DIMPAR / numthreadsperblock) + ((DIMPAR % numthreadsperblock)?1:0);
    printf("numthreadsperblock: %i;; numblocks:%i\n", numthreadsperblock, numblocks);

    //fill in host code
    for(i = 0 ; i < DIMPAR ; i++){
        h_pos[i] = 1;
        h_pbest[i] = 1;
    }

    //transf. to device memory
    cudaMemcpy(d_pos, h_pos, DIMPAR * sizeof( float ), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_pbest, h_pbest, DIMPAR * sizeof( float ), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    kernel<<<numblocks,numthreadsperblock>>>(d_pos, d_pbest);
    cudaMemcpy(h_pos, d_pos, DIMPAR * sizeof( float ), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost); 



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the full error message is something like this:

```
First-chance exception at 0x7c812a5b in myapp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location 0x0031fc24...
```

You should do proper [cuda error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) in your CUDA codes (but I ran your code and didn't see any obvious API errors).

If you have no CUDA errors being reported by the above method (proper CUDA error checking), then you can safely ignore this error.  It is resulting from an exception that is trapped and properly handled within the CUDA libraries that get linked to your code.

Your application will still run normally, and if you run the executable outside of Visual Studio, I believe you will not see this message.

You might try updating to CUDA 5.5 to see if this particular message goes away.

As another indicator, you can run your app with `cuda-memcheck` and it will also check for various kinds of errors.

Comment: Hi, I change my code. I put this:      <br/>   `kernel<<<numblocks,numthreadsperblock>>>(d_pos, d_pbest);
 gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
 gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );`  <br/>And now I receive this error:  <br/>`First-chance exception at 0x75ed812f in TEMP.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cudaError_enum at memory location 0x0040fc4c..
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1c24) has exited with code 30 (0x1e).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1a38) has exited with code 30 (0x1e).
The program '[5232] TEMP.exe: Native' has exited with code 30 (0x1e).`

Comment: Please edit your original question with the complete modified code.  Which version of CUDA are you using?  Which version of Visual Studio are you using?